# 2.79VSE -Any way to add external Vfx plugins

Tags: video-sequence-editor

In other softwares like Premiere,Vegas etc it's possible to share the same external Vfx plugins like NewBlue , BorisFx etc across softwares  .Is there any way to add these plugins in the VSE ?

Comment: My advise is not to use blender as a video editor and use any of the software you mention. For a free, not open source but highly functional editing app, use Resolve. Blender is a very poor tool for video editing.

Comment: yeah ,Blender does lack a lot of features compared to advanced editors like Resolve ,but it's workflow is  faster than most other editors.If they could just provide a way to add external plugins ,it would be so much better.